# java signature and signed data

Tags: java, signature

What is the difference between signature and signed data? I need to pass them to other side.

I do have code:

```
private static byte[] sign(byte[] data) {
    byte[] signedData = null;

    try {
        java.security.KeyStore keyStoreFile = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStoreFile.load(new FileInputStream("keyStore.pfx"),
                "password".toCharArray());

        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStoreFile.getKey(
                "alias", "password".toCharArray());

        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        dsa.initSign(privateKey);
        dsa.update(data);
        signedData = dsa.sign();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return signedData;
}
```

So is `signedData` a signature or signed data? I need to generate and post them both, but I don't understand the difference. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc of Signature.sign:

> Returns the signature bytes of all the data updated. The format of the signature depends on the underlying signature scheme.

So this is definitely not signed data but only the signature for the data supplied using the `update` method.

Comment: thank you, gabuzo, then how do I sign the data? do you have code example? as where I look I find only how to make a signature :|

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `data` is the original data, what you want to sign.  `signedData` is the signature data.  If you use the same private key and the same `data` you will always get the same `signedData` out.

Once you bundle together `data` and `signedData` I think you can call the resulting bundle the "signed data".  The original data is what you want to make available, and the signature data is how you or anyone else can confirm that the original data hasn't been altered.  In other words, in order to use the original data, you just need the original data; in order to verify that the data hasn't been changed, you need the original data, the signature data, and the public key.  (The public key has to be the one that matches the private key that was used to generate the signature data.)

For the verify operation to succeed, the verify software needs to have, as input, the exact same input that the original signing operation had.  So however you bundle together the original data and the signature data, you need to be careful not to add or delete any part of the data.

You could put the original data in a file, the signature data in another file, and make a zip archive or any other sort of archive.  You could Base64-encode both and put them together in a text file with delimiters.  Whatever.  But the end-user of the data needs the original data, the signature data, and the public key to verify that the original data is correct.